# For all but the last in Django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Is there a way to do some logic for all runs of a for loop just not the last in a Django template?

Specifically, for something like the below:

```
{% for e in emails %}
    {{e.email_address}};
{% endfor %}
```

The ';' gets included each time but ultimately I would like to ignore it on the last run. I have similar use cases for similar gramatical tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the implementation of [`join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#join) for templates.

```
{{ emails|join:"; " }}
```

> If emails is the list ['a', 'b', 'c'], the output will be the string "a; b; c".

Comment: This appears to break by character though?

Comment: @NickP In your example you would do `{{ emails|join:"; " }}`. (well, if emails were a list of emails, not objects that you need to extract the email from).